# When should I use Pipes or gRPC for interprocess communication (in C# .NET Core)?

Tags: c#, ipc, grpc, named-pipes, asp.net-core-5.0

Both [Pipes](https://www.developerfusion.com/article/84438/isolated-storage/) and ASP.NET Core gRPC support [local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/interprocess?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and remote IPC/RPC (with some platform limitations for gRPC)

> When would I use one technology (Pipes) or the other (gRPC)?

Observations, thoughts and considerations I'm keeping in mind:

- gRPC seems to be geared towards replacing WCF in some future iteration.
- local deployments and with machine restrictions (running as non-admin/user, machine firewalls, different platforms/OS)
- network traversal, and compatibility with same-machine -> multi-machine (frontend/backend arrays) for load and expansion
- Spanning secure zones (where a Proxy is used, or other TLS cipher/order/registry setting) affects the ability for HTTP/2 to work
- Pipes (named pipes?) have a different surface area and port (do they also use port 135, or NetBIOS over TCP (not sure of name))... how is it scanned and secured?
- "memory mapped files" seem to be a challenge to get working, however it seems to work in ASP.NET Core with gRPC in the UDS configuration. Is this a correct inference?

Right now my scenario is to have two console apps communicate with each other, same machine or remote. Adding Asp.NET Core Web is an optional front end alternative for my scenario.

Comment: Remote named pipes: just say no. You don't want to get in bed with NetBIOS if you can help it. Local named pipes are fine but offer little advantage over a local TCP connection if you're going to be allowing/requiring remote scenarios anyway. If all communication will be strictly local it's hard to beat them in terms of speed (shared memory can but is far more difficult to program around, at least on Windows).

Comment: @JeroenMostert is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/interprocess?view=aspnetcore-5.0) using shared memory, or is it a shared lock on a file?

Comment: I'm also unclear if "Pipes" linked above equates to NetBIOS. Would that also mean it might propagate to WINS naming system, or could? Just trying to see the complete picture.

Comment: gRPC is HTTP with a specific payload so your question becomes `Should I use pipes or HTTP`?

Comment: which platform limitations for gRPC?

Comment: @MarkusDresch (MacOS, AppService)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @TLDR: domain sockets are not shared memory, they are implemented in the kernel as a separate driver (much like named pipes). Of course named pipes and domain sockets *and* local TCP sockets technically all boil down to some form of memory sharing under the covers, since the data never leaves the machine, but only memory-mapped views over file mappings are "proper" shared memory. (Despite the name "file mapping", if the "file" is backed by the paging system no disk access need be involved, so none of these things really use files.)

Comment: Named pipes do not use NetBIOS themselves, but the protocols for remote named pipe communication are built on NetBIOS. The problems of NetBIOS are many and varied -- performance and security were never cornerstones. Remote named pipes are simply not an attractive proposition for any modern application -- not portable, not scalable, not secure by default. Local named pipes don't have this problem but they're Windows only, which is why UDS was added, serving much the same scenario but portably. Only TCP or for specialized scenarios UDP are really worth considering for remote connections.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 4):

### Simple IPC

Depends on how much communication is going to happen. If your communication is limited to simple collaborative signal passing or sharing some data between two processes you can safely use [NamedPipeClientStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream) and [NamedPipeServerStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream) on local system or local network but if you plan for the same on different systems then I would suggest using [TcpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient) and [TcpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener).

### Comprehensive IPC

WCF or now its replacement gRPC is for scenario where a complete API/Framework need to be executed remotely. For example I have an entire library of classes which I need to call from a different process (which mostly run on a different system); in that case gRPC kind of solutions make more sense.

**Only you can decide.**

This is a design decision which is highly unique for your application; your future plans and your system environment and any third person can only give you clues but ultimately you are the only person who can make the right decision.

Comment: Thank you. How/where would you consider SignalR, Websockets, or REST APIs in contrast to the IPC way of doing things?

Comment: @TLDR REST APIs can be as comprehensive for Web applications as gRPC in general. WebSocket is very low level API for web and SignalR is user friendly layer over WebSockets but still it should be used for rather simple communications.